# Inspecting instances of non-public classes using java.bean API

Tags: java, clojure, javabeans, introspection

I'm attempting to use Clojure's `(bean obj)` to retrieve an immutable map related to an object.

In the Clojure 1.4.0 standard library, this is implemented roughly like so (translating into pseudocode intended accessible to folks unfamiliar with Clojure):

```
import java.beans.PropertyDescriptor;
import java.beans.Introspector;

function introspect(Object obj) {
  Class clazz = obj.getClass();
  PropertyDescriptor descriptors[] =
    Introspector
    .getBeanInfo(clazz)
    .getPropertyDescriptors();
  Map retval = new HashMap();

  for(pd in descriptors) {
    name = pd.getName();
    method = pd.getReadMethod();
    if(method.getParameterTypes().length != 0)
      continue;
    retval.set(name, method.invoke(obj, nil));
  }
  /* the real implementation does more magic below here,
     but the above is sufficient for this question */
  return retval;
}
```

For the most part, this works fine -- [java.bean.Introspector](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/beans/Introspector.html) doesn't return non-public methods in its default [BeanInfo](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/beans/BeanInfo.html) implementation. However, when the object being inspected is an instance of a non-public class, it returns public methods on that class -- even though these can't actually be invoked without raising an `IllegalArgumentException` ("Can't call public method of non-public class").

How can this be fixed? I'm looking through the documentation for [java.lang.Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html), and I don't see an obvious way to determine a class's permissions that doesn't involve a try/catch block for [java.lang.SecurityException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/SecurityException.html)... which doesn't exactly strike me as likely to be a best practice. Moreover, in the case where a method on a non-public class implements a public interface, some mechanism should be available to determine that this method can be safely called.

Answer (score 2):

You can discover the modifiers on a class, so something like this should allow you to check whether an object is an instance of a private class (not heavily tested)

```
public boolean isInstanceOfPrivateClass(Object o) {
    return Modifier.isPrivate(o.getClass().getModifiers());
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, in the case where a private class implements a public interface, this answer is not, on its own, sufficient to determine that methods defined through that interface are accessible. In conjunction with a way to identify the interface from the PropertyDescriptor, it would probably be sufficient.

Comment: If an object is of a class that implements an interface (which are public by definition) then you should be able to call the methods on the interface regardless of the privacy of the class. Anything else is a bug. Note that Java has a lot of unnecessary baggage here caused by the way inner classes were added to the language. Private classes only make sense as inner classes. There may be something in the structure of your example that I'm missing.

Comment: I have a non-public class with a number of public methods. Some of those methods can be called publicly by virtue of the class implementing interfaces; some of those public methods cannot be called because they are not defined by any public class or interface, but only within the non-public class itself. The real-world use case driving this is `com.atlassian.crowd.embedded.ofbiz.OfBizUser`, from Atlassian's Crowd product, used in Jira; I agree that it doesn't make sense for them to have a public method on a non-public class, but my only control over that is filing a ticket suggesting as much.

Comment: You're right, by the way, that my first comment here was inaccurate -- the problem is determining whether a public method is defined through any interface, or whether it is defined only within the non-public class.

Comment: Actually -- non-public interfaces exist. Back to the real-world jira use case, `com.atlassian.crowd.embedded.ofbiz.IdName` is precisely that.

Comment: I've updated the answer with details of ``isAccessble()`` on ``Method``. This should work for you I think. The fact that non-public interfaces can only be declared in member interfaces and all methods must be public is a 'feature' of inner classes that we should do without IMHO.

Comment: Everything I've tested, even `Object.toString`, returns false for `isAccessible`. Reviewing the docs, it appears that this flag is used to override normal access controls, not to reflect them.

Comment: oops - you're absolutely right, i've used this to tweak accessibility at runtime, but hadn't dug in enough. My bad - removing that from the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This issue can be solved by searching the inheritance tree for a public class or interface containing the same method. In Clojure, this can be implemented (albeit with poor performance) as follows:

```
(defn- public-version-of-method [^Method method]
   "returns a Method built against a public interface or superclass
   declaring this method, or nil if none exists"
   (let [sig (method-sig method)]
     (loop [current-class (. method (getDeclaringClass))
            pending-supers (seq (supers current-class))]
       (if (and current-class
                (Modifier/isPublic (.getModifiers current-class))
                (some (fn [x] (= sig (method-sig x)))
                      (. current-class (getDeclaredMethods))))
         (. current-class (getDeclaredMethod
                           (.getName method)
                           (.getParameterTypes method)))
         (if pending-supers
           (recur (first pending-supers)
                  (next pending-supers))
           nil)))))
```

...and then calling `.invoke` on `(public-version-of-method m)` rather than `m` (if it returns a non-nil value), or accepting that the method is not publicly accessible if this method returns a nil value.

(The above code has been submitted upstream as part of a proposed patch for [CLJ-978](http://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJ-978)).

Comment: +1 - it shouldn't be this difficult :-), For reference Apache commons-beanutils has similar: http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/apache/commons/beanutils/MethodUtils.java.html#771

Comment: @sw1nn Thank you for pointing out the Apache Commons implementation -- that's exceedingly helpful!